# App Engine BitBucket connector shows no repositories

Tags: google-app-engine, bitbucket

I want to connect App Engine to BitBucket and I get this message:

[image]

> You do not have any repositories to connect. Please create a repository on Bitbucket first.

And actually I do have the code in BB. Some private and some others public. Is there any aditional consideration or something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've read that Group Repos are not available yet. :/ http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.mx/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html

Comment: I've just discovered that the Bitbucket repo must use Git, not Mercurial, to show up in App Engine

Comment: That's right and you must not add anything (like misc files, design files or other folders) but the source code in it on root.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, as you pointed only personal repositories are currently supported. As it's a feature in Preview Release, chances are that group repos will be added in the not so far future.